# UIImagePickerController must be used from main thread only | app crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

Hi everyone I am implementing `UIImagePickerController` in **iOS 14**. When the user selects the camera my app crashes when the user agrees to use the camera, returning this error in purple on xcode

```
- [UIImagePickerController init] must be used from main thread only
```

How can I solve this problem?
thanks everyone for the advice

```
private func cameraAuth(auth sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
    switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
    case .denied: imagePickerAuthDenied()
    case .restricted: imagePickerAuthRestricted()
    case .authorized: showImagePicker(sourceType: sourceType)
   
    case .notDetermined:

        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (success) in
            if success { self.showImagePicker(sourceType: sourceType) }
            else { self.imagePickerAuthDenied() }
        }
        
    default : print("Default Switch Camera Auth")
    }
}

private func showImagePicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
   
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for clarification, anything related to UI (modifying the UI etc) should be done only on main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap code inside `authorizationStatus/AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (success) in` in  `DispatchQueue.main.async`

```
AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
     ///
   }
}
```

---

```
AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (success) in 
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
     ///
   }
}
```

Comment: You've got an odd duplication of the code in our answer.